# How to create a two dimensional matrix on Stata

Tags: matrix, stata

if the below question is not for "two-dimensional" matrix then apologies but that's how I thought a two-dimensional matrix is defined.

I am trying to create a matrix where I want mean of a variable "X" by income quintile. I created the matrix for X as follow:

```
tabstat X [aw=weight] if location==1 & own==1, by(inc_quint) save

tabstatmat X, nototal

return list

matrix urbown = (r(Stat1) \ r(Stat2) \ r(Stat3) \ r(Stat4) \ r(Stat5))

matrix rownames urbown = `r(name1)' `r(name2)' `r(name3)' `r(name4)' `r(name5)'

matrix list urbown

svmat urbown
```

This creates the matrix for variable X but when I sort the data by income quintile, it does not give me data by quintile so I am wondering how I can include quintiles as well in the matrix. Any help or hints will be helpful!

Comment: Although I think what you want is clear enough, this isn't a reproducible example. The Stata tag wiki gives very detailed advice about showing code that we can run.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I think I should have mentioned that I want various matrices (depending on dummies own & location) to append with a different dataset and then use them to generate a specific variable. This is the reason why I didn't consider collapse.

Comment: So that is a different question.

Comment: I thought if I save the data I need as matrix (if it is possible to create matrix using 2 variables : decile & X in my case) and then append/merge with another data, it will do the job. I understand there are multiple ways to do it but it would be helpful for me to know how to create a matrix with 2 variables.

Comment: I suggest that you ask a different question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

All matrices have rows and columns, even if the number of either is 1. So, all matrices are two-dimensional. What you want is just a particular (one-way) table. Although your code ends with `svmat` you don't spell out why you want a matrix: the main reason for wanting a Stata matrix is to manipulate it further.

There are many ways of getting a table of means into a form suitable for further use.  Here is one: Use `collapse` to get a new dataset. The example is a little contrived but shows that nothing rules out, as in your code, (1) weights (2) an `if` qualifier as well as (0) using a five way breakdown, or similar.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. collapse price [aw=weight] if !foreign, by(rep78)

. list

     +-----------------+
     | rep78     price |
     |-----------------|
  1. |     1   4,608.6 |
  2. |     2   6,230.2 |
  3. |     3   7,142.2 |
  4. |     4   6,099.9 |
  5. |     5   4,186.5 |
     |-----------------|
  6. |     .     4,758 |
     +-----------------+
```